# node-sql-parser , parser.astify(sqlquery) not returning exact output

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to parse an sql query in nodejs using node-sql-parser.

```
const {Parser} = require('node-sql-parser');
const parser = new Parser();
const ast = parser.astify(sqlQuery)
```

the sqluery used is below

```
SELECT * FROM SUBSCRIPTION WHERE COLUMN_1 = 'NORM' AND COLUMN_2 IN ('11','12','13','14','15','16','17','18','42','43','44','45','101','102','103','104','128','129','130','131','159') AND (COLUMN_3 IS NOT NULL OR COLUMN_4 = 1) AND COLUMN_5 <> 1 AND (COLUMN_6 <> '8088' AND COLUMN_7 <>  '9088')
```

while parsing am getting the ouput

```
{ with: null,
  type: 'select',
  options: null,
  distinct: null,
  columns: '*',
  from: [ { db: null, table: 'SUBSCRIPTION', as: null } ],
  where:
   { type: 'binary_expr',
     operator: 'AND',
     left:
      { type: 'binary_expr',
        operator: 'AND',
        left: [Object],
        right: [Object] },
     right:
      { type: 'binary_expr',
        operator: 'AND',
        left: [Object],
        right: [Object],
        parentheses: true } },
  groupby: null,
  having: null,
  orderby: null,
  limit: null }
```

Where I am not able to iterate through **left:[Object]**.
Is there any way i can parse through this and only get a list of operators?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are logging it as an object that is why you see object in that. You need to `JSON.stringify(ast)` the object before consoling to see everything.

Regarding finding all the operators, you could use this code

```
const sqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM SUBSCRIPTION WHERE COLUMN_1 = 'NORM' AND COLUMN_2 IN ('11','12','13','14','15','16','17','18','42','43','44','45','101','102','103','104','128','129','130','131','159') AND (COLUMN_3 IS NOT NULL OR COLUMN_4 = 1) AND COLUMN_5 <> 1 AND (COLUMN_6 <> '8088' AND COLUMN_7 <>  '9088')";
const {Parser} = require('node-sql-parser');
const parser = new Parser();
const ast = parser.astify(sqlQuery)

function getOperator(obj, result = []) {
  let value;
  Object.keys(obj).forEach(key => {
    value = obj[key];
    if (value instanceof Object) {
      getOperator(value, result);
    } else if (key === "operator") {
      result.push(value);
    }
  });
  return result;
}

console.log(getOperator(ast));

// output will be -  ["AND", "AND","AND","AND","=","IN","OR","IS NOT","=","<>","AND","<>","<>"]
```

Comment: Thanks , this had helped me get the list of operators and also for other keyval